# Scale only if the type is std::complex

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I have the following template function:

```
template <typename T0>
struct ComplexTypeTraits
{
    using type = T0;
};

template <typename T0>
struct ComplexTypeTraits<std::complex<T0> >
{
    using type = T0;
};
template<typename T>
void myFunction(T& out, const T & in)
{
    using T1 = typename ComplexTypeTraits<T>::type; // will be 'T' for std::complex<T>

    out = in;
    if(std::is_same<T, T1>::value == false)
    {// if the type is std::complex<T>, do a scaling
        const T1 theta = M_PI/2.0;
        const T y(std::cos(theta),-1*std::sin(theta));
        out = out*y;
    }
}
```

The following call to the function works:

```
    std::complex<float> in(10, 5);
    std::complex<float> out = 0;
    myFunction<std::complex<float>>(out, in);
    std::cout<<"out is: "<<out<<std::endl;
```

However, when I call the function in the following way, is gives the error  "excess elements in scalar initializer.

```
float in = 10;
float out = 0;
myFunction<float>(out, in);
```

Basically, I would like to do a scaling, if the argument type is std::complex. How to solve the issue?
    std::cout<<"out is: "<

Comment: I'm not well acquainted with templates in C++, but I believe you can use "explicit specialization" to provide type dependent behaviors in templates: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function doesn't compile because the line `const T y(std::cos(theta),-1*std::sin(theta));` still needs to be valid; it's not when `T = float`.

This would be easy to solve with C++17's constexpr if:

```
if constexpr (std::is_same<T, T1>::value == false)
```

If you cannot use C++17, you can use tag dispatching:

```
template<typename T>
struct is_complex : std::false_type {};
template<typename T>
struct is_complex<std::complex<T>> : std::true_type {};

template<typename T>
void myFunction_impl(T& out, const T& in, std::false_type)
{
    // Nothing to do
}

template<typename T>
void myFunction_impl(T& out, const T& in, std::true_type)
{
    // T is a std::complex, do scaling
    const typename T::value_type theta = M_PI/2.0;
    const T y(std::cos(theta),-1*std::sin(theta));
    out = out*y;
}

template<typename T>
void myFunction(T& out, const T& in)
{
    out = in;
    myFunction_impl(out, in, is_complex<T>{});
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0f7510355651bdf4)

Note that directly overloading doesn't work because a `std::complex<T>` argument would be resolved as `std::complex<std::complex<T>>` when trying to choose the correct overload.